# Killing a subprogram created by other program when its killed

Tags: c, linux

I'm writting a C program that launches another program using the `system()` function. I'd want to know if there is a possible way to kill the program that is launched, if the main program is killed. I'm programming it for a Linux machine.
Example:

```
/* foo.c */
int main()
{
    system("./blah");
    return 0;
}
```

blah does whatever has to do. If I kill foo, blah is still running.
Is there any way to make foo to kill blah when it dies ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to work with *signal handling* to know when someone/something is trying to kill your application, read the below documentation for further information.

- **[linuxjournal.com - The Linux Signal Model](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3985)**

---

Besides that you'll need to know the *process id* of your spawned *child* process. For this I'd recommend to use something more sophisticated than `system` to fire up your launched process.

- **[yolinux.com - Fork, Exec and Process control](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html)**

---

You'll also have to know how to kill the spawned *child* (using it's `pid`).

- **[pubs.opengroup.org - functions: `kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/kill.html)**

Comment: You cannot catch/handle SIGKILL (also SIGSTP, SIGCONT).

Comment: @sirgeorge .. and you downvoted my answer for that, or is it just a weird coincidence? I have said nothing about `SIGKILL`. **if you** are confusing the use of `kill` with `SIGKILL` then I'm sad to say that you've got it all mixed up.